# NServiceBus pattern for working with events from common shared services

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

We have a situation where several of our services are shared across our system. For example one that tracks stock movements. Whenever the stock level of an article changes an event is raised.

The problem we run in to is that while sometimes another service may be interested in ALL stock change events (for example to do some aggregation), in most cases only stock changes that are the result of a specific action are interesting.

The problem we now face is this. Say have an IArticleStockChangedEvent event that contains the article number, the stock change and a ProcessId that requested the change. This event is raised for every change in the article stock.

Now some external service has a saga to change 10 articles and commands the stock service to make it so. It also implements IHandleMessages to keep track of the progress. This works well in theory, but in practise this means that the service containing this saga will be flooded with unrelated IArticleStockChangedEvent message for which it will be unable to find a corresponding saga instance. While not technically breaking anything it causes unnecessary delays in the system.

I'm not really looking forward to creating a new kind of IArticleStockChangedEvent for every saga that can possibly cause a stock change. What is the recommended approach to handle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider and decide against having the saga interact with that other endpoint in a request/response fashion? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: To be honest, I have thought about it, but there are two things holding me back. First the 'StockChanged' event is fairly generic and is also used by other services that DO want to know all of them. I'm not sure if I can 'reply' to the original service but ALSO send the event to all the other services that want to see everything. Secondly there are some layers of abstraction in place. The event comes from the domain aggregates that add the events to their internal lists. The moment the events are actually dispatched is in a different part of the code that has no knowledge of the situation.

Comment: Well, there's nothing technically preventing you from doing both a Reply (possibly of a different message type) as well as a Publish in a given message handler. But yeah, layers of abstraction do tend to make things more difficult - sometimes to the point that the cost outweighs the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The knowledge about which `IArticleStockChangedEvent` events you need to be delivered to your service lives inside your "external" service and changes dynamically, so it's not possible (or is complex and non-scalable) to make a filter in either Stock service or at a transport level (Ex. Service Bus subscription filter).

To make an optimization, namely avoid deserialization of the `IArticleStockChangedEvent`, you might consider custom `Behavior<IIncomingPhysicalMessageContext>` where you read the `Stock` item's `Id` from message header and lookup db to see if there is any saga for that stock item and if not, short circuit the message processing.

Better solution might be to use [Reply](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/reply-to-a-message) and reply with a message from `Stock` service.